# tiff from writeRaster does not open

Tags: r, tiff, raster

I'm doing some raster calculations and then I'd like to write the results to a new tiff. However, the output .tif from writeRaster in R does not open in any of the commonly used image vizualization softwares. Any suggestion please on what I should add to my code in order to correct that?
Thanks in advance,

```
setwd()

library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

band530.2 <- raster("TTC001270001.tif", band=2)
band530.3 <- raster("TTC001270001.tif", band=3)
band530 <- 4 * band530.2 + (band530.2 - band530.3)

lf<- function(x,a,b) {
  v <- getValues(x)
  v <- a * v + b
  x <- setValues(x, v)
  return(x)
}

calib.band530 <- lf(band530, 0.0009842088, -0.04702277)

writeRaster(calib.band530, filename="cTTC001270001.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: You could try `writeTiff` from the `tiff` package.

Comment: @G5W Thank you for the suggestion. I tried `writeTIFF` from the `tiff` package. It gives Error in writeTIFF(calib.band530, "cTTC001270001.tif") : image must be a matrix or array of raw or real numbers. I also tried `writeTiff` from the `rtiff` package. Error in writeTiff(calib.band530, "cTTC001270001.tif") : writeTiff expects a pixmapRGB or matrix, got  RasterLayer. Then, I don't know how I could convert my raster layer to those format `writeTIFF` or `writeTiff` expect, without missing information on the pixels.

Comment: Have you checked calib.band530 for illegal image values?  Maybe try to put bounds on the output before writing.

Comment: @Dan Slone Thank you for the suggestion. Indeed I had few pixels with negative value. I just tried converting them to NA or 0 before writing the tiff but the problem remains the same. What you said as putting bounds on the output, sorry I don't know what is that. Could you please share any link for that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your code makes a perfectly useable geo-tiff that opened in ArcGIS just fine.

If you want to view the output in a normal image viewer, you can convert it to a regular raster:

```
tiff("test.tif",dim(calib.band530)[2],dim(calib.band530)[1]) 
grid.raster(as.raster(calib.band530),interpolate=FALSE) 
dev.off()
```

This will eliminate the geospatial information.

To create a viewable geo-tiff, you need to rescale the data if you want it to be viewable by humans, then add one more parameter for the color space.  This works for me:

```
calib.band_rezero <- calib.band530 - cellStats(calib.band530,min)
calib.band_stretch <- calib.band_rezero / cellStats(calib.band_rezero,max) *254
writeRaster(calib.band_stretch, filename="cTTC001270001_viewable.tif", format="GTiff",datatype='INT1U', overwrite=TRUE)
```

Just adding the color space parameter will make it open in an image viewer, but will probably look black:

```
writeRaster(calib.band530, filename="cTTC001270001.tif", format="GTiff",datatype='INT1U', overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Geotiff will typically not display in photo viewer.